# How to get timezone from iso time string in Python?

Tags: python, time, utc

For instance this:

`my_timestamp = '2022-01-02T02:00:02-08:00'`

We know that `+00:00` is considered UTC, this timestamp `-08:00` indicates `America/Los_Angeles`.

Is there any way to explicitly get that information using any date function in python?

For instance:

```
my_timestamp = '2022-01-02T02:00:02-08:00' # iso string
implicit_tz = someFunction(my_timestamp) # return the string "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the methods in the `datetime` module?

Comment: Are you asking how to split the `-08:00` part from the string or how to look up the location "Los Angeles" given `-08:00`?

Comment: @Barmar yes I did, I couldnt find a method that gives the name of the timezone in a string. Please correct me I am wrong

Comment: @mkrieger1 how to get the "America/Los_Angeles"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a human-readable timezone name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489183/how-can-i-get-a-human-readable-timezone-name-in-python)

Comment: "this timestamp -08:00 indicates America/Los_Angeles." Or America/Tijuana. Or America/Vancouver. Or Pacific/Pitcairn. How do you want your function to choose?

Comment: @Sören `America/Los_Angeles.` preferably

Comment: But it shouldnt matter really

Comment: You can use `dateutil.parser.parse` to convert your timestamp string into a `datetime` object that has a `tzoffset`. Then look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085289/getting-timezone-name-from-utc-offset to get a name from the offset. There can be multiple names for the same offset which is why this is not as trivial as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above, this code will output all the possible timezones for your ISO string.
Is up to you which one to choose.

```
from dateutil.parser import isoparse
import dateutil.tz as dtz
import pytz
my_timestamp = '2022-01-02T02:00:02-08:00' # iso string
my_timestamp_parsed = isoparse(my_timestamp)
my_timezone = isoparse(my_timestamp).tzinfo
for name in pytz.common_timezones:
    timezone=dtz.gettz(name)
    try:
        if timezone.utcoffset(my_timestamp_parsed) == my_timezone.utcoffset(my_timestamp_parsed):
            print(name)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```