# Convert ZoneInfo to Pytz timezone name

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a datetime string such as `date = "2023-06-16T07:46:00-03:00"`

Extracting timezone information from it give me the following results:

```
>>> formatted_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

>>> formatted_date.tzinfo

datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=75600))

>>> formatted_date.tzinfo.tzname(formatted_date)

'UTC-03:00'
```

The problem is, I need the timezone information to be something like `America/Los_Angeles`, in order to use with PostgreSQL EXTRACT function.

Is there a package or a function in Pytz that convert this tzinfo to a name such as the example I gave?

Comment: `-03:00` is an offset from UTC, not a time zone in a geographical sense like "America/Los_Angeles". Multiple time zones can share the same UTC offset on a given date, so an unambiguous attribution of UTC offset --> time zone is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FObersteiner commented here about the UTC-03:00 being just an offset and not timezone info.

With this information I was able to find [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085289/getting-timezone-name-from-utc-offset) that contains a solution to convert the offset to a timezone list.

For this application it won't matter if the user is in Timezone A or B, if both are the same Offset, I just need a name in order to use the Postgres function, so it works.

Comment: still sounds a bit hacky to me ^^ anyways, make sure to not use datetime.now() as suggested in the linked Q&A, instead use the datetime you already have. And finally, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) if you can, pytz is deprecated.